# Filtering for specific words in cells with lists of names

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtering, vba

congratulations for this forum first of all. I have a problem which maybe someone me can help me with.

I have an excel file with a several columns, the first column is made of cells containing **each** of them a list of names. I should filter that column for let's say 3 names - so that all the cells which have **1,2 or all 3 of those names** included in the list are filtered in.
I tried with advanced filtering, found a macro, other formulas - still cannot make it. If this is even possible, you are my last hope :) It' important that that It works like a filter (i.e. I don't loose the other columns), it's not enough that I just extract the relevant cells from the 1st column.

Many thanks in advance everyone!
Luca

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site expects individual effort and then you get help on specific item (not the whole problem)!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can filter the names one at a time, but making sure that you select the ***"Add to current selection to filter on the succeeding filters"***